# Вывод иконки папки рядом с папкой

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь вывести иконку папки рядом с папкой, но у меня получается, что сначала выводится иконка, а потом всё остальное, я не понимаю, как правильно сделать.

[image: Мой результат]

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; char set=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tmp';

$images = array('papka.jpg');

$dir = 'C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\kurs\16\dzfm';
$files1 = scandir($dir);


?>

<?php
    if(is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])){
        foreach ($images as $img){
    }
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>">
    <?php print_r($files1)?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Картинку, наверное, стоит внутрь цикла поместить? Хотя, какая разница, она там одна.

Comment: "Я пытаюсь вывести иконку папки рядом с папкой, но у меня получается, что сначала выводится иконка" - бред какой-то.

Comment: `foreach(new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $filename => $fileInfo){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$img = 'papka.jpg';

$dir = 'C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\kurs\16\dzfm';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $f) {
   if (is_dir(dir . '/' . $f)) {
      echo '<img src="' . $img . '">';
   }
   echo $f, ' ';
}
```

Естественно вывод необходимо более культурно оформить.